# Check if email and username exist in PHP and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to check if a handle or email exists for the riegistration on my mock Twitter project I'm doing called bleeter, but I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in first.php on line 20

This is the line where I check if `num_rows_handle == 0`. How am I supposed to do this?

```
$query_check_handle = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE handle = " . $handle;
$num_rows_handle = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_handle);
if ($num_rows_handle == 0) { // Line 20
    //check email
    $query_check_email = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = " . $email;
    $num_rows_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_email);
    if ($num_rows_email == 0) {
        $query_register = "INSERT INTO users (first_name,  last_name, handle, password, email, ACL) 
                        VALUES ('$fname', '$lname',  '$handle', '$pass', '$email', '$ACL')"
        or DIE ("error running the query.");
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query_register);        
        echo "<br>";
        echo "You have succesfully registered, please login";
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Email already in use.  Please try again";
    }
} else {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Handle already in use.  Please try again";
}
```

Comment: The [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function [returns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues) a [`mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. Your line 20 comparison is essentially trying to compare an `int` to an arbitrary object. The `mysqli_result` object has a `num_rows` property.

Answer (score 0):

When the query is `SELECT`, `mysqli_query` returns the object of type `mysqli_result`, which has property `num_rows` containing the number of rows. Thus

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_email);
$num_rows_email = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: i tried that and it registered someone even if the email existed and it gave me this notice Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Elizabeth\Documents\UniServer\www\bleeter\first.php on line 25 ($num_rows_email = $result->num_rows;)